# Is there any parameter in pandas.read_excel() to properly deal with the "=" character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file (xlsx format) where some rows start with "'=The user reviewed the app as...".
When I read the file using `pd.read_excel()`, these rows become NaNs.
However, when I first convert the file to csv and then use `pd.read_csv`, these type of rows are properly imported in a dataframe (it seems that it automatically handles the '= character and replace with "")

I already tried to use:
`pd.read_excel(data, converters={"'='" : ''})` but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to still import the file using `pd.read_excel()` in a properly manner?

Comment: I could read it in my first test. Could you share an example of file content exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about this option?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\your_path_here\\Book1.xlsx',  read_only=True)

ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Read the cell values into a list of lists
data_rows = []
for row in ws['A1':'F20']:
    data_cols = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

# Transform into dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
df
```

Result:

```
       0     1     2     3     4          5
0  Hello  None  None  None  None       None
1   None  None  None  None  None       None
2   None  None  None  None  None       None
3   None  None  None  None  None       None
4   None  None  None  None  None       None
5   None  None  None  None  None       None
6   None  None  None  None  None       None
7   None  None  None  None  None       None
8   None  None  None  None  None       None
9   None  None  None  None  None  Hey There
```

[image]